# Example for a class that is not PAC learnable

Tags: machine-learning, pac-learning

I'm looking for a reference (with proof) on hypothesis classes that are not PAC learnable. Is there a simple one too? Are they of any use (if not in practice, maybe as counter examples for some claims)?

Answer (score 1):

A hypothesis class is not PAC learnable if it has infinite VC dimension, for example the class of polynomial classifiers over $\mathbb{R}$ , or the class of unions of intervals H = ${\cup_{i=1}^{k}{[a_i, b_i]}| k \in \mathbb{R} a_i \leq b_i}$